# can anyone help me with the correct Cron Expression

Tags: java, spring, cron

I want to run my scheduler everyday night 10 o'clock. Which of the following is correct?

```
@Scheduled(cron = " 0 0 22 * * ?", zone = "America/Los_Angeles")
@Scheduled(cron = " 0 22 * * * ", zone = "America/Los_Angeles")
```

Comment: You need to use relevant tags please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 22 * * *")` it says 'Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 5 in "0 22 * * *")error on start.

in springboot application use:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 22 * * ?")
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 22 * * *
```

It will run every first minute of 10 pm, that means 10 pm everyday.

Comment: but if i give like that my springboot application is being terminated immediately once it gets started

Comment: If it is getting started at that time, that means cron expression is correct. It is getting terminated because whatever you are doing inside the job code, that is finished. It is not related to cron schedule. You need to check the actual job.